# Таймер для опубликованной статьи на Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2, doctrine

На сайте есть элемент в котором публикуется акция недели (только одна!),у данной статьи должен быть выставлен срок публикации по выбору , а так же срок истечения.

Если время публикации истекло , данной строке должен быть присвоен статус 0.

В базе данных, может быть только одна строка со статусом 1

Функция должна отклонять запрос публикации, если вы хотите установить дату публикации / истечения между датами существующей строки

Answer (score 2):

В принципе, в PHP есть [некоторое подобие таймера](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/event.timer.php), но скорее всего он будет работать пока выполняется процесс.

Обычно такие задачи на PHP решают по другому.

- Пишется скрипт, который проверяет истёк ли срок публикации и т.п. и выполняет в связи с этим те или иные действия;
- Вышеуказанный скрипт периодически запускается по CRON, что обеспечивает его автоматическое выполнение с заданной периодичностью.